# Create Firebase Reference without Error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently having a problem to create a proper Firebase reference for my iOS app. I am already having trouble with this the whole day and just can't find how to fix it.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var remoteSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

    //That's where i get the Error ! --> Expected declaration
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Would be nice if someone could tell me how to properly assign a Firebase Database Reference in iOS 10, Xcode 8.

Firebase Setup was successful until this point. No errors and everything was set up with podfile etc...

ThankYou.

## Question Update

ThankYou @ ronatory for your tip to create the reference in the viewDidload. That worked.

I am able to write into the Firebase from the viewDidLoad Function now. 
But I still have problems when i want to assign additional UI Switches to write Data into the Database.

```
    import UIKit
    import Firebase
    import FirebaseDatabase

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet var remoteSwitch: UISwitch!
        @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
            ref.child("timeo").setValue(true)
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        @IBAction func switched(_ sender: UISwitch) {
            if remoteSwitch.isOn == true {
                label.text = "ON"
//location *
                ref.child("timeo").setValue(true)
            }
            else {
                label.text = "OFF"
//location *
                ref.child("timeo").setValue(false)
            }
        }

    }
```

I think there is a problem with the scopes there, because it shows the error at location * that It doesn't knows these variables.

Would be very nice if someone can help me with that. Thanks.

Timeo

**Update**

[image: That's the Error I get when declaring the Reference in the]

Comment: You need to put `ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()` in a method like `viewDidLoad` for example. Sure it gives an error right now because you try to assign it in the class scope

Comment: @ronatory check update

Comment: added my answer to your updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

You create and initialize the `ref` constant in your `viewDidLoad()` and because of that it's only available inside the scope of `viewDidLoad()`.

**Solution:**

To access it also inside other methods like your `switched(_:)` method, you need to create a reference with type of `FIRDatabaseReference` and then you can initialize it in `viewDidLoad()` to be able to set your values after that (Hints are in the code comments):

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var remoteSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    // create the reference here
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // initialize your reference
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        ref.child("timeo").setValue(true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func switched(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if remoteSwitch.isOn == true {
            label.text = "ON"
            // now you should be able to access your reference here
            ref.child("timeo").setValue(true)
        }
        else {
            label.text = "OFF"
            // now you should be able to access your reference also here
            ref.child("timeo").setValue(false)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank You so much you helped me so much. Struggling wit that the whole day. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, great that I could help you! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can make it direct like this:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var remoteSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
    }



}
```

Also make sure you had the Pod installed:

```
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```